# something wrong with my makefile about wildcard

Tags: linux, make, c

I have a bunch of `.c` test source file in directory `tests/`. Now I want to compile and link them respectively and output the executable `*.out` in `tests/`. So I wrote a makefile, which didn't work.

```
# ...
TestDir := tests
TestSourceFile := $(shell sh -c "ls tests/*.c")
TestTargetFile := $(subst .c,.out,$(TestSourceFile))

TestFrame := testframe.o

TestNeededObjectFile := $(TestFrame) \
    + util.o \
    + tokennames.o \
    + lex.yy.o \
    + hex.o \

.PHONY: test-%

test-%: $(TestDir)/%.out
    $^

.PHONY: test

test: $(TestTargetFile)
    @for t in $(TestTargetFile); do \
        $$t ; \
    done

$(TestDir)/%.out: $(TestDir)/%.o $(TestNeededObjectFile)
    gcc -o $@ $^

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $^

clean:
    rm -rf *.o lextest *.yy.? *.tab.? *.output $(TokenNameFile) \
        $(TestDir)/*.out
```

When I run `make test-add`(`add.c` is in `tests/`), I am expecting to see `add.out` in `tests/` but instead there is an error:

```
> make test-add
make: *** No rule to make target 'tests/add.out', needed by 'test-add'.  Stop.
```

I want to know how to write this makefile correctly and why this makefile is wrong.

Comment: Did you add those plus signs next to the object files? It's not the only thing that's wrong, but they're definitely not helping

Comment: @Kusalananda the `%.foo: bar.%` pattern subst from GNU make doesn't care about `.SUFFIXES`; it does care about the existence of the requisites, though.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks, I wasn't sure how GNU `make` handles these types of pattern targets.

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) in GNU make won't be considered if their prerequisites do not resolve to existing files, either directly or recursively via other pattern rules[1]:

```
$ make -f <(echo '%.foo: %.bar file.txt;') a.foo
make: *** No rule to make target 'a.foo'.  Stop.

$ touch a.bar
$ make -f <(echo '%.foo: %.bar file.txt;') a.foo
make: *** No rule to make target 'a.foo'.  Stop.

$ touch a.bar file.txt
$ make -f <(echo '%.foo: %.bar file.txt;') a.foo
make: 'a.foo' is up to date.
```

Since your `TestNeededObjectFile` macro includes spurious `+`s, and you probably don't have any file named that way, that will break the `$(TestDir)/%.out:` rule.

[1] according to the GNU make [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro):

> In order for the pattern rule to apply, its target pattern must match the file name under consideration and all of its prerequisites (after pattern substitution) must name files that exist or can be made. These files become prerequisites of the target.